# Programmatically reading crash logs in Objective C in an OSX / cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to be able to read a crash log and send it to my server. I've seen libraries that do this, and I'm actually basing my code on them -- except many of them seem out of date, which is why I believe I'm currently having a problem with OSX sandboxing.

There seem to be 2 parts to any generated crash log. In `/Users/zane/Library/Containers/**[BUNDLE_ID]**/Data/Library/Application Support/CrashReporter` there is a `.plist` with not much information. One thing it does contain, though, is a `Path` to `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/**FULL_CRASH_FILE**.crash`

However, when I try to open this full path via `[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile...]` I get a read access error:

`Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “Aftermath_2014-02-12-210934_inZania.crash” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo=0x600000264700 {NSFilePath=/Users/zane/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Aftermath_2014-02-12-210934_inZania.crash, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000246900 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"}`

I take it that this is a problem with entitlements/sandboxing. Is there any way I can gain access to this file, or otherwise get a full stack trace to send to my crash reporter?

Comment: You may try to create a bookmark to the file URL and use that with com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope set to YES.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I spent 2 days refactoring FeedbackReporter to accomplish crash reports handling. All work shot to hell due to sandbox.

Comment: Nope, I haven't had any luck with this at all. The bookmark thing was a good idea, but it doesn't escape the sandboxing: trying to create the bookmark has the same error.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the permissions of the log file!! It may need root permissions to access!

Comment: Perhaps you could ask for clarificaiton on whether the OP has considered this in comments rather than proposing it as a solution?